# Want to know the time complexity inner for loop which is partially iterating the array

Tags: time-complexity

**Question:** Find out next increasing value of each element in this below array.

```
int[] array = { 5, 2, 7, 10, 4, 12}
```

e.g) 
     5's nextIncreasingValue: 7 
     2's nextIncreasingValue: 7 
     7's nextIncreasingValue: 10 
     ... 
     12's nextIncreasingValue: -1

**Implementation:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int nextIncreasingValue = -1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[j] > array[i]) {
            nextIncreasingValue  = array[j];
            break;
        }  
    }
    PRINT("For " + i + "th next increasing value is: " + j)
}
```

Now I want to know the time complexity of this program, since each time inner for loop is skipping some of the elements on iteration. So it cannot be O(n^2) even in the worst case.

Kindly explain me what will be the time complexity?

**O(n) Solution using stack:**

```
Stack s = new Stack();
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   while(!s.isEmpty() && array[i] > s.peek()) {
         PRINT  s.pop() NIV is array[i];
   }
   s.push(array[i]);
}
while(!s.isEmpty()) 
   PRINT  s.pop() NIV is -1;
```

Comment: Remember, big-O is an *upper* bound so even if the inner loop executed once for each iteration of the outer loop, we could still say the time complexity of the algorithm was $O(n^2)$ (even if it were actually a linear function of $n$). You probably should ask for the "best" big-O estimate or perhaps a big-Theta estimate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It **is** $O(n^2)$. Consider `array = [n, n-1, n-2, ..., 1]`.

---

BTW, you could implement this in $O(n)$ by scanning from the end of the array:

- Suppose the next-increasing-value (NIV) of `a[i+1]` is `x`.
- We want to find the NIV of `a[i]`, which we observe that:

  1. If `a[i+1] > a[i]`, then the NIV is `a[i+1]`
  2. If `x > a[i]`, then the NIV is `x`
  3. Otherwise, `a[i]` is already the maximum value, so the NIV = -1.

Using this we could work backward from `a[n-1]` to `a[0]` to find the NIV of each entry in $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Thanks! but i didn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Which part are you confused with?

Comment: 1) you told; It is O(n^2) ;  but How?    2) you mentioned array with (n, n-1, ...), what you are explaining in this declaraion     3) How it is possible with O(n) using from the end? since i need next greater number...

Comment: 1&2) The array demonstrates the worst-case scenario which your implementation requires $O(n^2)$ operations to complete. With a decreasing array it will never enter the `if` so the inner loop won't be `break`'en and there will be $O(n^2)$ operations.

Comment: Yeah Thats good point :) but still the start point j is i+1 right; so increment of i will keep reducing j iteration correct na ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar But $N+(N-1)+(N-2)+\dotsb+1=\frac12N(N+1)$ is still $O(N^2)$.

Comment: oooh! That is great point to add.

Comment: Just curious; Do you have any blog which contains those of such equations and its values? where you referred from?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar This is just a standard [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). And you will see lots of these in any introductory CS course :).

Comment: It will be great if you could provide program for O(n) instead of words, since i am not able to understand it.

Comment: I tried to implement this here but it didn't work.  I think maybe it would work if the array never had repeated values, but with e.g. [4, 3, 4, 5] it doesn't work because for the 4 at position 0, the next number (3) is not bigger, and the next number's NIV (4) is also not bigger, so we get -1 when we should get 5.  https://gist.github.com/user896724/4567e61587219ff39d27db04647e754e.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don't have that rep yet on this stackexchange.

kennytm's answer is right, I just want to add my rule of thumb:

whenever you are iterating over an array/list/other linear data structure, regardless of how many elements you skip or how early you break out, the big-O notation is always O(n).  Whenever you call that iteration from another loop, regardless of how far into the array you start, or how quickly you break out, it becomes O(n^2).  Maybe you can see the pattern now.

Comment: This is just wrong. First, there is no unique way of expressing a function using big-O. When you say that iterating over an array is always $O(n)$, that's kinda true but if, say,  you break out after $\log n$ operations, it's also $O(\log n)$. And if you iterate inside another loop, the running time will depend entirely on how many times _that_ loop iterates, which isn't necessarily $\Theta(n)$.